# Terraform plan -var-file="myvars.vars" does not run

Tags: terraform

I try to lean terraform for usage with our AWS environment.
I have created a .tf file and terraform init was successful.

In the .tf file I have a number of variables that are populated via .var files (not **.tfvar**) because I want to assign values per instance/project etc.

The problem is that when I run the command

```
terraform plan -var-file="myvars.var"
```

all I get is the terraform usage message.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3):

You define variables in `variables.tf` file. However, you can define inputs to these defined variables in a `.tfvars`(recommended) or any other files.

> Values for the input variables of a root module can be gathered in variable definition files and passed together using the -var-file=FILE option.
>
> For all files which match terraform.tfvars or *.auto.tfvars present in the current directory, Terraform automatically loads them to populate variables. If the file is located somewhere else, you can pass the path to the file using the -var-file flag. It is recommended to name such files with names ending in .tfvars.
>   [more...](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#variable-files)

Make sure you are running `terraform plan` from the directory where the variable file resides.

Comment: I do! It is in the same directory! The documentation says that I can use whatever filename is want, as long as I specify it in the -var-file. 

The directory has the following files:


create_instance.tf, general variables.tf, myvars.var

Comment: Yes, you could use whatever file name you want. The same command works for me, except if the file is missing, or probably running it from a different directory. Would you mind to paste exact output you get when you run the command?

Comment: terraform  plan -var-file="my-vars.vars"

invalid value "my-vars.vars" for flag -var-file: multiple map declarations not supported for variables
Usage: terraform plan [options] [DIR-OR-PLAN]

Comment: Sorry, wrong output (I was in another directory, sorry).

Here is what I get:

terraform  plan -var-file=idm-vars.vars 
Usage: terraform plan [options] [DIR-OR-PLAN]

  Generates an execution plan for Terraform.                                                                                                                           

  This execution plan can be reviewed prior to running apply to get a                                                                                                  
  sense for what Terraform will do. Optionally, ...

Comment: What do you get if you run the `plan` command without `-var-file` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a typo in the var-file
I had a double " in a value:

```
varname = ""value"
```